# Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:geoflutterfire/geoflutterfire.dart'

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

[image]I'm not succeeding to import these two packages in my flutter app, im using Android Studio. I get these messages errors::

**Target of URI doesn't exist:**
**'package:geoflutterfire/geoflutterfire.dart'.**

**Target of URI doesn't exist:**
**'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart'.**

This is how i edited my **pubspec.yaml** file:::

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  location: ^4.4.0
  geolocator: ^9.0.2
  geocoding: ^2.1.0
  permission_handler: ^8.0.0+1
  firebase_core: ^2.10.0
  firebase_database: ^10.1.0
  cloud_firestore_platform_interface: ^5.12.0
  cloud_firestore_web: ^3.4.0
  collection: ^1.0.0
  meta: ^1.3.0
  geoflutterfire: 3.0.3
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.6
```

After that i exceuted the command : **flutter pub get**.

Comment: a code where you import it not correctly would be nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not have tried

```
flutter pub get
```

Comment: I tried but I'm getting a series of errors asking me to change the versions. When i change one version it keeps turning. This is what i get:::

Comment: Because cloud_firestore >=3.1.2 <4.0.1 depends on firebase_core ^1.10.2 and gab depends on firebase_core ^2.9.0, cloud_firestore >=3.1.2 <4.0.1 is forbidden.
So, because gab depends on cloud_firestore ^3.1.6, version solving failed.
pub get failed

Comment: Its because of incompatible versions, first tell me what flutter version you are using and try to use latest versions for  cloud_firestore  and firebase_core.